# Regex to match series and numbers starting with predefined characters

Tags: regex

Is it possible to match just the numbers from a predefined set of characters looking like:

`FACTURA SBG113151`

What I want: `113151`

What I'm trying: `FACTURA[ ]*([a-z0-9A-Z]+)`

What I get: `SBG113151`

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
FACTURA *[a-zA-Z]*([0-9]+)
FACTURA[^0-9]*([0-9]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RfkZ3p/2/). The point is to match and consume the chars before the digit sequence you need to extract.

*Details*:

- `FACTURA` - a word
- `*` - zero or more spaces
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more letters
- `[^0-9]*` - in the other regex, matches zero or more chars other than digits
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits

Comment: Thanks for the comment, It does the trick! Do you know how can I use it to match both letters and numbers from the end in a scenario like this? BZ and 347  `CUI: RO39890982                                                                          BZ 347`

Comment: Sorry, no idea what the rules here are. Try `CUI: *[a-zA-Z]*([0-9]+(?:\s*[a-zA-Z]+\s*[0-9]+)?)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/RfkZ3p/3)).

Comment: Hmm it matches the numbers numbers at the beginning starting with RO... Unfortunately I only want the 347 and BZ using two separate regexes preferrably

Comment: @shAkur Sorry, I do not see how this is related to your current question. `\b(?:[A-Z]{2}|\d{3})\b` [match](https://regex101.com/r/RfkZ3p/4) exactly what you need.